# lucene issue after migrate from wildfly1.0.0.final 1 to tomcat9.0.41

Tags: hibernate, tomcat, search, lucene

I have had a project under wildfly which was working correctly with following pom.xml,
after changing web application server without any changes on pom.xml, I see this log by testing project for lucene searches.

pom file is here :

```
    <properties>
            <java.compiler>1.8</java.compiler>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <ogm.version>4.1.1.Final</ogm.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    
            <version.org.hibernate.ogm>4.2.0.CR1</version.org.hibernate.ogm>
            <!--<version.org.wildfly>10</version.org.wildfly>-->
    
            <!--<jboss.home>${project.build.directory}/wildfly${version.org.wildfly}</jboss.home>-->
            <ogm.module.path>${project.build.directory}/hibernate-ogm-modules</ogm.module.path>
    
        </properties>
         <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.freeutils</groupId>
                <artifactId>jcharset</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.magicwerk</groupId>
                <artifactId>brownies-collections</artifactId>
                <version>0.9.13</version>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
                <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
                <version>3.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
                <version>7.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!--LOG-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.17</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.12</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.12</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Test-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.12</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.ibm.icu</groupId>
                <artifactId>icu4j</artifactId>
                <version>57.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--apache-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.10</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-compress</artifactId>
                <version>1.18</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
                <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--DNS-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>dnsjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>dnsjava</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.7</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Servlet API-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
                <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <!-- AspectJ dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
                <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.9</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--Validator-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <!--J2EE-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <!--Hibernate-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.2.Final</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
                <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.13</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.6.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- mysql-->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.42</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.3.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.3.Final</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
                <version>5.2.18.Final</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
                <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
                <artifactId>activemq-client</artifactId>
                <version>5.14.3</version>
            </dependency>
      <dependencies>
```

Error:
all crud process and connections to db are correct. just lucene searching have folling problem

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/AbstractQueryImpl
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:978)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:626)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:733)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at com.art.negar.servlet.filter.XSSCheckerFilter.doFilter(XSSCheckerFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CompositeFilter.doFilter(CompositeFilter.java:73)
    at com.art.negar.servlet.filter.AccessCheckerFilter.doFilter(AccessCheckerFilter.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:178)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:374)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:888)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1597)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/internal/AbstractQueryImpl
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2432)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1334)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    at org.hibernate.search.impl.FullTextSessionImpl.createFullTextQuery(FullTextSessionImpl.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.search.jpa.impl.FullTextEntityManagerImpl.createFullTextQuery(FullTextEntityManagerImpl.java:96)
    at com.art.negar.dao.impl.contact_management.ContactServiceImpl.list(ContactServiceImpl.java:320)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.list(Unknown Source)
    at com.art.negar.controller.contact_management.ContactController.contactList2(ContactController.java:1724)
    at com.art.negar.controller.contact_management.ContactController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$c2273ffd.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:721)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:656)
    at com.art.negar.controller.contact_management.ContactController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$c5cd0ce0.contactList2(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    ... 44 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.internal.AbstractQueryImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
    ... 87 more
```

myCode:

```
    org.hibernate.search.jpa.FullTextQuery jpaQuery =
                    fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(builder.build(), Contact.class);
```

my project libs:
[image]

my tomcat libs:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Wildfly is a full JAVA EE container that includes Hibernate as the JPA provider. Tomcat is only a Servlet container that doesn't provide any JPA provider.

So you need to remove de `<scope>provided</scope>` from the `hibernate-entitymanager` dependency because with Tomcat you will need to include them in your WAR.

Comment: tnx for your reply. I removed all <scope>provided</scope> tags.

Comment: I ve got error again but log is different now:

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/search/query/hibernate/impl/FullTextQueryImpl

Comment: You need to include the `hibernate-search-orm` dependency. It is by default on wildfly, but not on Tomcat

Comment: I already have this dependency on my pom.xml :

Comment: <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
                <version>5.5.3.Final</version>
            </dependency>

Comment: and can you verify it's packed inside your WAR?

Comment: sure, there is. this issue really confuse me

Comment: `org.hibernate.search.query.hibernate.impl.FullTextQueryImpl` it's inside the `hibernate-search-orm` dependency, so if it's inside your app, the classloader should find it. Could you post the contents of the `WEB-INF/lib` directory of your app, and the lib/ directory in TOMCAT?

Comment: I have edited post for wanted libraries. tnx

Comment: All seems ok. Check that the correct WAR is deployed and you don't have a stale version on Tomcat.